# NP-complete proof of subset with sum zero

Tags: algorithms, np-complete

I'm trying to proof that a problem of subset from a group has a sum of zero.
I know that i can use the partition problem that is known to be NP-complete, but i can't seems to find what i need to change in the group so it will give the sum of zero.

Thank you.

Comment: Please try to state your problem with better clarity

Comment: Sorry, English is not my native language. I will try to be more clear. i want to do a reduction from the partition problem to something similar to the subset-sum problem, with only one difference, there is no K (sum) only to check if there is a subset-sum of group S that it's sum is zero.

Comment: Fine. NP (No problem)

Answer (score 1):

So you want to reduce the partition problem to the subset sum problem.

**Hint:** Given an instance of the partition problem, sum the numbers and halve the sum to find out what each side of an equal partition must sum to. Append *minus* this number to the problem, and feed the resulting multiset to the hypothesized subset-sum solver.

Comment: So, if for example i have the group A that its sum is 18,  then A/2= 9 . afterwards, i will send -(A/2) to the input of the subset-sum(zero)?              I got this right?

Comment: @user3066968: Yes.

Comment: But in the subset-sum(zero) problem that i'm trying to reduce to , i have in the input of the problem  only a group S of n integers. Can i add another object to the input?

Comment: @user3066968: A reduction consists of taking an instance of one problem and _somehow_ constructing an instance of the other problem. It seems to be a perfectly cromulent way to construct an instance of subset-sum to say, "take all of these numbers, and that one as well".

Comment: Ok, but still , if i add -(S/2) to the input of the subset-sum(zero) problem, i don't understand how to say that only a sub of the group has a sum of zero. I do find that the whole group has a sum of zero. But again i need only a sub of the group. Hope i'm clear enough.

Comment: @user3066968: The new number will be the _only negative number_ in the subset-sum instance. So the only possible nontrivial way to get a sum of 0 will be to take that negative number, plus enough of the original numbers to sum to exactly $A/2$, which is just what a partition is.

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated